# WIre length in Conducted emission test

Tags: emc

What should be the Minimum or maximum input power cable length can be used in Conducted emission test.

Length from EUT(DUT) to LISN.

What if my product come with input cable length out of MAX limit.

Answer (score 2):

> It is preferable to use a standard unbundled 1m length of cable for
>   these tests, whatever the length that will be supplied with the final
>   product.

In other words: -

[image]

That is the advice given on [this](http://incompliancemag.com/article/guide-to-testing-conducted-emissions-part-2/) website (Guide to Testing Conducted Emissions (Based on the Methods in EN 55022 and EN 55011) – Part 2) for performing conducted emission tests.

Clearly, if you had a conducted emission problem, this could be "mitigated" by using a much longer cable therefore the 1m requirement has the intention of putting everyone on a level playing field.

Different specifications may have different cable-length requirements.

Comment: Thanks Andy, We use 0.8m length cable ( Lab engineer told to use this, even it not mention on standard), we did testing on 0.8m to consider worst case , but we fail at 18 Mhz by 2db, What you think if I go again with 1m input cable can solve this problem.??

Comment: Hard to say. Be prepared to fit ferrites is my advice.